# why dynamic values not populating in autocomplete combo box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, javascript-objects

I have referred many examples from jquery and StackOverflow questions. But no where given example for database values to add into autocomplete combobox. That's the reason I have opened this question here.

Please advise why array values are not populating into autocomplete combo box ? Here is [my sample coding](https://jsfiddle.net/stackoverflow/1sogae3d/23/)

```
   (function($) {
$.widget( "custom.combobox", {
    _create: function() {
      this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )
        .addClass( "custom-combobox" )
        .insertAfter( this.element );

      this.element.hide();
      this._createAutocomplete();
      this._createShowAllButton();
    },

    _createAutocomplete: function() {
      var selected = this.element.children( ":selected" ),
        value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";

      this.input = $( "<input>" )
        .appendTo( this.wrapper )
        .val( value )
        .attr( "title", "" )
        .addClass( "custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left" )
        .autocomplete({
          delay: 0,
          minLength: 3,
          source: $.proxy( this, "_source" )
        })
        .tooltip({
          tooltipClass: "ui-state-highlight"
        });

      this._on( this.input, {
        autocompleteselect: function( event, ui ) {
          ui.item.option.selected = true;
          this._trigger( "select", event, {
            item: ui.item.option
          });
        },

        autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
      });
    },

    _createShowAllButton: function() {
      var input = this.input,
        wasOpen = false;

      $( "<a>" )
        .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
        .attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
        .tooltip()
        .appendTo( this.wrapper )
        .button({
          icons: {
            primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
          },
          text: false
        })
        .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
        .addClass( "custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right" )
        .mousedown(function() {
          wasOpen = input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" );
        })
        .click(function() {
          input.focus();

          // Close if already visible
          if ( wasOpen ) {
            return;
          }

          // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
          input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
        });
    },

    _source: function( request, response ) {

     var autocompleteList = [];
     autocompleteList=['test1','test2','test3','test4'];
     if(autocompleteList.length>0){
      console.log(autocompleteList) ;
       for(var j=0;j<autocompleteList.length;j++){

        return {
          label:autocompleteList[j],
          value:autocompleteList[j],
          option:this
       }
      }

     }

    },

    _removeIfInvalid: function( event, ui ) {

      // Selected an item, nothing to do
      if ( ui.item ) {
        return;
      }

      // Search for a match (case-insensitive)
      var value = this.input.val(),
        valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
        valid = false;
      this.element.children( "option" ).each(function() {
        if ( $( this ).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase ) {
          this.selected = valid = true;
          return false;
        }
      });

      // Found a match, nothing to do
      if ( valid ) {
        return;
      }

      // Remove invalid value
      this.input
        .val( "" )
        .attr( "title", value + " didn't match any item" )
        .tooltip( "open" );
      this.element.val( "" );
      this._delay(function() {
        this.input.tooltip( "close" ).attr( "title", "" );
      }, 2500 );
      this.input.data( "ui-autocomplete" ).term = "";
    },

    _destroy: function() {
      this.wrapper.remove();
      this.element.show();
    }
  });
  })(jQuery);

  $(function() {
    $("#combobox").combobox({

    });

    //$("#combobox").closest(".ui-widget").find("input, button").prop("disabled", true);
});
```

HTML

```
 <div class="ui-widget">
  <select id="combobox">

</select>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide an example of the result data that is expected. What would `autocompleteList` look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

only change combobox select items; changing combobox select items automatically updates autocomplete

```
    $('#combobox').empty();
    for (var i = start_index; i < start_index + 4; i++) {
        $('#combobox').append(' <option value=test"' + i + '">test' + i + '</option>');
    }
```

```js
 $( function() {
   
   var autocompleteList = [];
     autocompleteList=['test1','test2','test3','test4'];
      
   for(var i=0; i<autocompleteList.length; i++){
     
             $('#combobox').append(' <option value="' + autocompleteList[i] + '">' + autocompleteList[i] + '</option>');

   }
   
    $.widget( "custom.combobox", {
      _create: function() {
        this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )
          .addClass( "custom-combobox" )
          .insertAfter( this.element );
 
        this.element.hide();
        this._createAutocomplete();
        this._createShowAllButton();
      },
 
      _createAutocomplete: function() {
        var selected = this.element.children( ":selected" ),
          value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";
 
        this.input = $( "<input>" )
          .appendTo( this.wrapper )
          .val( value )
          .attr( "title", "" )
          .addClass( "custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left" )
          .autocomplete({
            delay: 0,
            minLength: 0,
            source: $.proxy( this, "_source" )
          })
          .tooltip({
            classes: {
              "ui-tooltip": "ui-state-highlight"
            }
          });
 
        this._on( this.input, {
          autocompleteselect: function( event, ui ) {
            ui.item.option.selected = true;
            this._trigger( "select", event, {
              item: ui.item.option
            });
          },
 
          autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
        });
      },
 
      _createShowAllButton: function() {
        var input = this.input,
          wasOpen = false;
 
        $( "<a>" )
          .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
          .attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
          .tooltip()
          .appendTo( this.wrapper )
          .button({
            icons: {
              primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
            },
            text: false
          })
          .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
          .addClass( "custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right" )
          .on( "mousedown", function() {
            wasOpen = input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" );
          })
          .on( "click", function() {
            input.trigger( "focus" );
 
            // Close if already visible
            if ( wasOpen ) {
              return;
            }
 
            // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
            input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
          });
      },
 
      _source: function( request, response ) {
        var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
        response( this.element.children( "option" ).map(function() {
          var text = $( this ).text();
          if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
            return {
              label: text,
              value: text,
              option: this
            };
        }) );
      },
 
      _removeIfInvalid: function( event, ui ) {
 
        // Selected an item, nothing to do
        if ( ui.item ) {
          return;
        }
 
        // Search for a match (case-insensitive)
        var value = this.input.val(),
          valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
          valid = false;
        this.element.children( "option" ).each(function() {
          if ( $( this ).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase ) {
            this.selected = valid = true;
            return false;
          }
        });
 
        // Found a match, nothing to do
        if ( valid ) {
          return;
        }
 
        // Remove invalid value
        this.input
          .val( "" )
          .attr( "title", value + " didn't match any item" )
          .tooltip( "open" );
        this.element.val( "" );
        this._delay(function() {
          this.input.tooltip( "close" ).attr( "title", "" );
        }, 2500 );
        this.input.autocomplete( "instance" ).term = "";
      },
 
      _destroy: function() {
        this.wrapper.remove();
        this.element.show();
      }
    });
 
    $( "#combobox" ).combobox();
      $('.custom-combobox-input').val('');
   var start_index=5;
    $( "#btnUpdate" ).on( "click", function() {
      $('#combobox').empty();
    for (var i = start_index; i < start_index + 4; i++) {
        $('#combobox').append(' <option value=test"' + i + '">test' + i + '</option>');
    }
      
      $('.custom-combobox-input').val('');
      start_index+=5;
    });
  } );
```

```css
.custom-combobox-toggle {
     padding: 13px!important;
    margin-top: -2px!important;

}
.wrapper {
margin:30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="ui-widget">
  <select id="combobox">

</select>
</div>
<br>
<input type="button" id="btnUpdate" class="btn btn-default" value="update" >
<div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Values are loading but combo box option missing, it's just like input box .

Comment: it works like https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox. could you explain "combo box option"?  it filters when something written in it, shows all values when arrow clicked. have you look at https://codepen.io/peker-ercan/pen/LgxRjv

Comment: Your code working perfectly! But same implementation in my code drop down is not showing. Though i have used select tag in html but when loading data the drop down not showing.

Comment: could you add https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css css file

Comment: Yes, i have included below modules though i m getting error " [Show/hide message details.] TypeError: Bootstrap tooltips require Popper.js (https://popper.js.org)"                                                                            
 /jquery-3.3.1.min.js ,  /jquery-ui.min.js, /bootstrap.min.js ,/popper.min.js" type="module">

Comment: You should add jQuery js library, bootstrap js library, popper.js library jquery-ui js library and jQuery-ui css in that order.

Answer (score 3):

I would advise something like:

```
$(function() {
  $("#combobox").combobox({
    source: function(req, resp) {
      var autocompleteList = [];
      var results = [];
      session.run('MATCH (n) RETURN n.name').then(function(result) {
        $.each(result.records, function(k, r) {
          autocompleteList.push(r._fields[0]);
        });
      });
      if (req.term.length) {
        results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(autocompleteList, req.term);
      } else {
        results = autocompleteList;
      }
      resp(results);
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
      $('#log').text('selected ' + $("#combobox").val());
    }
  });
});
```

This will over ride the `source` callback and perform the needed activity to collect the full list, and if the user has typed anything, reduce the list to those items matching what was typed.

Since this combobox is custom, I do not think there is a `selected` callback. Autocomplete uses `select` callback. So I would try that first. Otherwise you can create a `selected` callback in your code.

Otherwise, collect your list before initializing your ComboBox. Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm collecting my list before initializing your ComboBox, but still list not coming to comobox box.    https://jsfiddle.net/stackoverflow/1sogae3d/23/

Comment: @user2848031 can you supply a example of the data? How do you collect it?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example on how to do it, I just created an array to loop over because I don't have access to the session object.

```js
var autocompleteList = [];

$(document).ready(function() {

 var records = ['test', 'test 2', 'test 3']

    records.forEach(function(record) {
      autocompleteList.push(record);
    });
    
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: autocompleteList
    });
    
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Adam. Sorry, I'm looking for autocomplete with combobox https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/combobox.html

Comment: You will need to override the  `_source` function and have that return your `autocompleteList` object

Comment: After added all the libraries , im getting an error TypeError: $(...).combobox is not a function

Comment: That usually means something is wrong with the jQueryUi include, double check those references.

Comment: Here is my code : https://jsfiddle.net/stackoverflow/1sogae3d/23/    Please let me know what am missing here.

Comment: Yeah, you don't have a reference to jQuery or jQueryUi anywhere in there.